# Converting Date field and Character Time field to DateTime

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have two fields that I am trying to combine into a DateTime field.  The first field is a DATE field and the second field is a *character* field that has the time in 24hour format.

For example:

field1: 10/02/13
field2: 19:58:18

How can I get this into a DATETIME field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DATETIME() function will do it for you:

```
mdate = DATE()
mtime = TIME()

? DATETIME(YEAR(mdate), MONTH(mdate), DAY(mdate), VAL(LEFT(mtime, 2)), VAL(SUBS(mtime, 3, 2)), VAL(RIGHT(mtime, 2)))
```

Comment: My date is 10/05/13 and my character time is 19:58:18.  When I do the conversion above, I get 10/05/13 07:00:00 PM.  Why is that?